# Linux can't find process started by PHP

Tags: php, linux, minecraft, gnu-screen

I'm currently running an own Minecraft Server, and I wanted to build an option to restart the Minecraft server via PHP, so my friends can restart the MC server without needing access to my actual server.

Thus, first I wanted to create a script to start the server:

**startup.php**

```
<?php 

    chdir('/home/minecraft/minecraft_server/');
    exec("./start");

?>
```

**start**

```
screen -mdS "minecraft_up" java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar server.jar nogui
```

After a bit of permission pain etc, by calling the webadress the server can be started.
Now, my problem is that I have no access to the screen process.

When running `ps -ef` I get:

```
     UID     PID    PPID  C   TTY        TIME CMD
www-data   29642       1  0     ?    00:00:00 SCREEN -mdS minecraft_up jav
www-data   29643   29642 99 pts/5    00:02:07 java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar serv
```

When running `sudo pwdx 29642` to get the process location I get:

```
29642: /home/minecraft/minecraft_server
```

But when I go into the `/home/minecraft/minecraft_server`directory and run either `screen -ls` or `sudo screen -ls`, both times I get:

```
No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-minecraft.
```

In contrast: When executing the start file manually in the terminal, when running `screen -ls` I can actually see the process (or open it with `screen -r`):

```
There is a screen on:
        29025.minecraft_up      (01/24/2021 01:32:45 PM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-minecraft.
```

I also get the same working directory, but I cannot run the start file manually while the process started py PHP is still running.

I'm really not an expert at all at Linux, I guess theres some user permission interference or something that PHP is treated as an own user, I really don't know, which is why I'm asking.

#### How do I access this process started by PHP?

Comment: Better to do it different way: create a service that run mine craft server, The service will keep mine-craft server running. Then create PHP script to restart the services when needed. if you need help write which linux are you using and I will write an answer in details.

Comment: That would be nice. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a service using `systemd` :

Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system/` called `minecraft-server.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft server 
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=minecraft
Group=appmgr
ExecStart=java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar server.jar

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Replace `server.jar` with full path.

Now lets create the new group and user.

To create new group run the following command:

```
sudo groupadd appmgr
```

Now lets create the new user and it it to a group.

```
sudo useradd –G appmgr minecraft
```

Now your service is created, we need to enable it and run it for first time.

```
systemctl enable minecraft-server
systemctl start minecraft-server
```

Last step to write php script to restart the services:

```
<?php 
    exec("systemctl restart minecraft-server");
?>
```